# Install OS X 10.7 to 10-10 on MacBook Air MD232

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have MacBook Air MD232. As we need to test our software on all OS X from 10.7 to 10.10, we need to install them all. Is it possible to install them on my MBA? When I buy, this MBA has been installed with Yosemite. I tried to install any other OSs by using "restore" feature from Disk Utility. However, restoring process were successful and pressing alt/option during restart, I get only gray screen with a stop sign and nothing happen afterwards. Would you please tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

## Hardware Requirements

Every Mac has a minimum supported operating system. Older versions of OS X will not run on a Mac with a higher minimum.

For example, the MacBook Air (Early 2014) **requires** OS X 10.9.2 or later.

EveryMac has a comprehensive [list of Mac models and their minimum supported OS X](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_capability/minimum-macos-supported.html).

### Virtual Machines

To work around this, consider using a virtual machine for your testing; [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/fr/products/desktop/), and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) are all reasonable choices.

Answer (score -1):

I understood correctly your question, you want to test your software on several versions of OS X. I think what you should do is partion your ssd into 4 parts for each OS X version. You can install any version of OS X using a usb key. How to create a bootable usb key with a OS X you can watch [THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyjWd2Bs57c)

So what I want to suggest you to do is make sure that the current files and documents from MBA are backed up

Restart the machine and hold ALT key, you will see a gray screen with two options, choose Disk Utility and from there you will have to erase the hard drive and patron it into 4 parts. You can watch [THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wf8yQMLqZA0) to see how do so. Even so in the video it is performed inside the OS X and on external drive the moves are the same.

After you partioned your drive you can start installing different versions of OS X with a usb stick, how to do it you can watch [THIS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOSxGrlnz7k)

Hope this helps

Comment: Instead of providing links to external sites where the relevant information can be deleted/replaced anytime could you please summarize the necessary steps directly in your answer?